# change value in piped delimited text file

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to use Notepad++ and change the value in a text value separated by |

There are 12 columns and I need to change the value in the 10th column to 99999

```
Program Name|Company Number|Supplier Name|Supplier ID|ID|Phone|Email|Bank Name|Job Number|Project Number|Account Type|Deposit Type|New or Update
AP|555|ABC Corp|V000004||111-111-1111||Franks Bank|11111111|1234|C|CCD|New  
AP|555|ABC Corp|V000004||111-111-1111||Franks Bank|11111123|3456|C|CCD|New
```

I tried this:

**Find :**

```
^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|(.*?)$
```

**Replace:**

```
^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|^(.*?)|9999
```

It put the value at the right place but wiped everything before and after out.

Comment: I count 13 columns. Two columns have no content. Is that correct? You can [edit] your question if necessary and send a short comment.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76766575/edit)and add expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^|]*\|){9}\K[^|]*`
- Replace with: `NEW VALUE`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(?:         # non capture group
    [^|]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a pipe
    \|          # a pipe
){9}        # end group, must appear 9 times
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[^|]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a pipe
```